# Postgres: Create function to delete an element with previous validation

Tags: postgresql, function

I'm trying to create a function in Postgres to delete a record, but validating if the record exists using 2 parameters:

```
CREATE FUNCTION editor.full_delete_node(_id uuid, _name character varying)
    RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 1
    VOLATILE PARALLEL SAFE
AS $BODY$
DECLARE 

BEGIN

IF exists(select 1 from editor.node WHERE id = _id AND name= _name) = false THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION SQLSTATE '90001';

DELETE FROM editor.nodE WHERE id = _id AND name = _name;
    
DELETE FROM editor.graPHIC WHERE id = _id AND name = _name;
    
DELETE FROM editor.topology WHERE id = _id AND name = _name;

END
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION editor.full_del_nodo(uuid, character varying)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

But Postgres tells me the following error:

[image: Error in second $BODY$ tag]

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: No matching `END IF;` for `IF ... THEN`. See [Conditionals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS)

Comment: Thanks for your help, i solved a few errors above and didn't realize the END IF;